# imported android studio project cannot be built

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import android studio project. When is imported, it cannot be built and shows just two files (local.properties,gradle-wrapper.properties).

It is not showing any errors. Any idea what should I do?

Comment: You probably imported the wrong directory. Try the root directory of the project.

Comment: This is also happen if the imported project have issues and gradle can not build it.